# Facebook app requesting Youtube watch history

Tags: facebook-graph-api, youtube-api

We are working on an idea of a FB app which let's us retrieve youtube watch histories of app users.
I know there's the possibility to retrieve watch histories through youtube's api, but in combination with a FB app I couldn't find examples.

Any input on this is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two are orthogonal.  Since you didn't specify a language, I'll assume you're using Python.

1. Write an [FB app using Canvas](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) to display output to users ... I assume you are using Canvas.
2. Use the [YouTube API and Python client](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python) to make API calls. You'll need to use a database or some other storage engine to link a user's Facebook API auth token with their Google auth token. Both are using OAuth 2.0 (though they are different flavors), so once you learn one, the other should be easy.

Before I answer anymore questions, it's probably a good idea for you to work through the getting started guides for both Facebook's API and YouTube API first. After you have some understanding of both, pick a stack and you should more or less be ready to go.

Comment: Thanks, the linkage between the two tokens gives me a good idea of the setup already.